# Como usar Foreach com xslt em um arquivo xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Não estou conseguindo usar um arquivo **".xml"** e um arquivo **".xslt"**

Segue abaixo o código: **listaAlunos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listaAlunos>
  <aluno>
    <nome>Bill</nome>
    <sobrenome>Gates</sobrenome>
  </aluno>  
   <aluno>
    <nome>Steve</nome>
    <sobrenome>Jobs</sobrenome>
  </aluno> 
  <aluno>
    <nome>Mark</nome>
    <sobrenome>Zuckerberg</sobrenome>
  </aluno>  
  <aluno>
    <nome>Larry</nome>
    <sobrenome>Page</sobrenome>
  </aluno>
  <aluno>
    <nome>Orkut</nome>
    <sobrenome>Buyukkokten</sobrenome>
  </aluno>

</listaAlunos>
```

O outro arquivo é esse: **foreach.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Alunos da Sala</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Sobrenome</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/listaAlunos/aluno">
         <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="nome"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sobrenome"/></td>
         </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode processar o arquivo XML usando um processador XSLT para gerar um HTML (via ferramenta ou servidor) ou vincular usando uma instrução de processamento (que será interpretada pelo browser). Para fazer esse vínculo, acrescente a linha abaixo no arquivo XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="foreach.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>
```

Assumindo que os dois estão no mesmo diretório e que serão carregados diretamente pelo browser ou através de um servidor Web que enviará os arquivos como texto, XML simples ou HTML.

O efeito resultante será o HTML abaixo:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Alunos da Sala</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Sobrenome</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Bill</td>
            <td>Gates</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Steve</td>
            <td>Jobs</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Zuckerberg</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>Page</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Orkut</td>
            <td>Buyukkokten</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```